# Assigning multiple values to a subsection?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Is there an easy way to add multiple attributes/properties to a section in a document?
I want for example add some sort of rating to a product that is discussed in a subsection.

Example:

```
\section{Product A}
\label{sec:proda}
\rating{10}
```

Later in a large table I want to list all products and their rating, including hyperlink to the section where the product description is located. Therefore the rating should be best accessible using the label of the section:

```
\nameref{sec:proda} (\ref{sec:proda) & \ratingref{sec:proda}
```

Is there a not too complex solution that allows something like that?

Comment: What would the `\rating` command do, exactly? Add  something like `Rating: 10%` at the end of the subsection tile, or in the margin, or whatever you can imagine (crimson gothic letters in a footnote…)?

Comment: The `\rating` command should just set the rating attribute of the currents section. It should not produce anything visible in the document.

Answer (score 3):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) provides the means to create a property list than can be referenced, thereby extending the default `\label`-`\ref` system to include more than just the last label and page number.

The following provides such a solution with a mild change in interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref,zref-titleref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{section}[0]{\thesection}% New reference property
\zref@newprop{rating}[0]{\therating}% New reference property
%\zref@newprop{default}[]{..}% Already defined by zref
%\zref@newprop{title}[]{..}% Already defined by zref
%\zref@newprop{page}[]{..}% Already defined by zref
\zref@newlist{product}% Create a new list of properties
\zref@addprops{product}{default,section,rating,title,page}

\newcommand{\productlabel}[1]{% Label product
  \label{#1}% For hyperref
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{product}}% For zref
\newcommand{\rating}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{rating}{#1}}
\newcommand{\productref}[2][default]{\hyperref[#2]{\zref@extract{#2}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Product A}
\rating{10}
\productlabel{sec:proda}

See \productref[title]{sec:proda} (\productref[section]{sec:proda} \& \productref[rating]{sec:proda}).
\end{document}
```

For each product, create a `\productlabel{<label>}` that stores the `title` (of the `\section`), `section` number or `default`, the `rating` (set by `\productrating{<rating>}`) and the `page` number. You can reference these using `\productref[<type>]{<label>}`.

It's compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as expected (same package author).

Comment: The zref package sounds perfect. However I want to stick with the standard command `\label`as my LaTeX editor recognizes them. Would it cause any problems to just renew the `\label` command instead of creating a new `\productlabel`?

Comment: @Robert: Not if you don't use anything else. Note though that `\productlabel` uses `\label` in its definition as it needs some interface with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (as per your request). So you'll have to use something like `\let\oldlabel\label \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1} ...}` (not tested...).

Answer (score 2):

Here I introde `\ratedsection{<title>}{<label>}{<rating>}` and `\showrating{<label>}`, along with the requested forms of `\nameref` and `\ratingref`.  The `\showrating` macro is intended to build a `tabular` line of data all at once.

Obviously, one could define `\ratedsubsection`, etc., as needed.

EDITED to add `hyperref` package to the preamble.

REEDITED to support `tabular` construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\ratedsection[3]{\section{#1}\label{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname product#2\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname rating#2\endcsname{#3}%
}
\newcommand\showrating[1]{%
  \nameref{#1}& \ratingref{#1} &\ref{#1}%
}
\newcommand\nameref[1]{\csname product#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\ratingref[1]{\csname rating#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\ratedsection{Product A}{sec:proda}{10}
blah
\ratedsection{Product B}{sec:prodb}{15}
more blah

\section{conclusions}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\centering
\caption{Products and their ratings}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
Product Name & Rating & Section\\
\hline
\showrating{sec:proda}\\
\showrating{sec:prodb}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately something like the `\ratedsection` command is not usable in my case as don't want to replace the standard `\section` and `label` command. This is because of LaTex editor does recognize them and shows the document outline e.g. for navigation which is really helpful in long documents.